# Unable to connect to redis docker container from inside jenkins docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, redis, docker-compose

I am running Jenkins inside a docker container like this

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
  jenkins:
    image: jenkinsci/blueocean
    user: root
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
      - ./jenkins_data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And this is my Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent { docker { image 'python:3.7.0' } }
  environment { 
        ENV = 'test'
    }
  stages {
    stage('install dependencies') {
      steps {
        sh 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
      }
    }

    stage('test') {
      steps {
        sh 'python app/tests/test_user.py'
      }   
    }
 }
```

- To run test files, Flask app need to connect to redis. I tried to use these urls for redis host like **localhost:6379, redis:6379, 0.0.0.0:6379** but nothing work. They all gave me connection error or connection refused.
- Any idea how to connect to redis from inside jenkins docker container ?.

Comment: redis should be available as `redis:6379`, you don't have to define `ports` section if you don't want to expose service outside of internal network

Comment: could you please define "but nothing work" more specifically, what is the error message you are getting

Comment: `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known. `. It gave me this error when I try to connect to redis. I don't understand why it doesn't work ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
version: '3'
```

does not work.

but

```
version: '2'
```

works

This is my test

```
 32       image: daocloud.io/mysql:5.7.21
 33       ports:
 34        - "3306:3306"
 35       volumes:
 36        - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
 37       environment:
 38        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dangerous
 39     mysql3307:
 40       image: daocloud.io/mysql:5.6
 41       ports:
 42        - "3307:3306"
 43       environment:
 44        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dangerous
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a5317caa2a56        daocloud.io/mysql:5.7.21   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   service_mysql_1
9c5e3f2750f9        daocloud.io/mysql:5.6      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   service_mysql3307_1
```

In 9c5e3f2750f9 I run it

```
mysql -u root -pdangerous -h mysql
```

It works, but when I change version to '3'.

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'msyql' (0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I thought the `link` was deprecated. By default, containers in docker-compose file all join a default network. So I should be connect to redis by calling redis:6379 right ?. But it gave me the `name or service not known ` error ..

Comment: I get it, try `redis ` instead of `redis:6379`.Use inside the container does not need to define a port section

Comment: I tried `redis` instead of `redis:6379` but it still give the same error `Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known`. I don't understand what is happening in here

Comment: I test it and found version: '2' work but version: '3' doesn't

Comment: Thank you. Let me give it a try. I still don't understand what is happening in the background haha

Comment: Well it didn't work for me. I have to install redis-server inside the python image and connect to it with the url `localhost:6379`